# Is it possible to set width of a jQGrid in percentage?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

Is it possible to set width of a jQGrid in percentage? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 17):

It's possible in very simple way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var pageWidth = $("#updatesList").parent().width() - 100;
$("#updatesList").jqGrid({
    url:'quick_updates.php?action=loadUpdates'+"&request=ajax",
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:[table_heading_id, table_heading_products, table_heading_categories, table_heading_model, table_heading_availability, table_heading_weight, table_heading_quantity, table_heading_sortorder, table_heading_manufacturers, table_heading_price, table_heading_tax],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:(pageWidth*(5/100)), sortable:true, align:"center", search:true},
        {name:'name',index:'name', width:(pageWidth*(20/100)), sortable:true, align:"left",true:false,resizable:true},
        {name:'categories',index:'categories', width:(pageWidth*(10/100)), sortable:true, align:"left",resizable:true,search:true,stype:"select",searchoptions:{value:categories}},
        {name:'model',index:'model', width:(pageWidth*(10/100)), sortable:false, align:"left",search:true,resizable:true,editable:true},
        {name:'availability',index:'availability', width:(pageWidth*(10/100)), sortable:true, align:"left",resizable:true,search:true,stype:"select",searchoptions:{value:availability},editable:true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:availability}},
        {name:'weight',index:'weight', width:(pageWidth*(5/100)), sortable:true, align:"center",search:false,editable:true},
        {name:'quantity',index:'quantity', width:(pageWidth*(5/100)), sortable:true, align:"center",search:false,editable:true},
        {name:'sortorder',index:'sortorder', width:(pageWidth*(5/100)), sortable:true, align:"center",search:false,editable:true},
        {name:'manufacturers',index:'manufacturers', width:(pageWidth*(10/100)), sortable:true, align:"left",resizable:true,search:true,stype:"select",searchoptions:{value:manufacturers},editable:true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:manufacturers}},
        {name:'price',index:'price', width:(pageWidth*(10/100)), sortable:false, align:"center",search:false},
        {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:(pageWidth*(10/100)), sortable:true, align:"center",resizable:true,search:true,stype:"select",searchoptions:{value:taxes},editable:true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:taxes}}
    ],
    rowNum:50,
    rowList:[10,20,30,50,100],
```

look at this code:

```
var pageWidth = $("#updatesList").parent().width() - 100;
```

and this code:

```
{name:'id',index:'id', width:(pageWidth*(5/100)), sortable:true, align:"center", search:true},
        {name:'name',index:'name', width:(pageWidth*(20/100)),
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Like the trick. But will it work when user changes the resolution or change the size of the browser without page load? Can you send me any demo site where i can see.

Comment: I achieved it using window resize event.

Answer (score 16):

Not directly but it is possible...

If you are wanting to set the width of the entire grid to a percentage you can use the autowidth property and it will set the grids width to the width of it's parent element (i.e. DIV) and that parent element can have it's percentage set.

```
autowidth: true
```

If you want to set the column widths by percentage you can use shrinktofit and then your column width values are basically a percentage.

```
shrinkToFit: true
```

These options and many others can be found on the JQGrid [wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions)

Answer (score 5):

Datatables 3.5+ supports this via

```
      jQuery("#dt").jqGrid({
                autowidth: true,
                shrinkToFit: true
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

As for me, I consider this to be the best deсision:

```
// add this after JqGrid creation
$("#YourTableGrid").setGridWidth( Math.round($(window).width(), true) );
```

Answer (score 1):

check window size in jquery.

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {
        var newWidth = $("#list").closest(".ui-jqgrid").parent().width();
        $("#list").jqGrid("setGridWidth", newWidth, true);
});
```

make sure to set autowidth: true in grid properties

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to set the width of the jqgrid table on your HTML page, try this.

**HTML**

```
<table id="jqGrid" width="98%"></table>
```

**JS**

```
var outerwidth = $("#jqGrid").width();

$("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
   width: outerwidth
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var operationfieldwidth = 40
    function getPercentage(ask)
    {
        return ((screen.width - operationfieldwidth) * ask) / 100;
    }

    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        GridBind();
    });
    function GridBind() {
        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
            url: '@(Url.Action("BindRole", "Role"))',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'Get',
            colNames: ["Role Name", "Role Description", ""],
            colModel: [{ name: 'ActRoleName', index: 'RoleName', width: getPercentage(20), align: 'left', power: 3, sortable: true },
                       { name: 'ADRoleName', index: 'RoleDesc', width: getPercentage(80), align: 'left', power: 6, sortable: true },
                       { name: 'add', sortable: false, width: operationfieldwidth, search: false, power: 0, formatter: addLink }
            ],
            pager: jQuery('#jqControls'),
            iconSet: "fontAwesome",
            rowNum: 25,
            rowList: [25, 50, 100, 500, 1000],
            height: screen.height - 490,
            viewrecords: true,
            emptyrecords: 'No Records are Available to Display',
            jsonReader: {
                root: "rows",
                page: "page",
                total: "total",
                records: "records",
                repeatitems: false,
                Id: "0"
            },
            autowidth: true,
            multiselect: false,
        }).navGrid('#jqControls', {
            edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: true,
            searchtext: "Search", refresh: true
        }, {}, {}, {},
       {
           zIndex: 100,
           caption: "Search Record",
           sopt: ['cn'],
           closeAfterSearch: true
       });
    }
    function addLink(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        var Str = "<a class='fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-2x' style='cursor:pointer;' href='../../Role/AddEditRole?id=" + rowObject.ID + "'></a>"
        return Str;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready(function () {
     var yourPercentage = 50%;
     $("#jQGridDemo").setGridWidth($("#jQGridDemo").parent().width() * yourPercentage/100);
 });`

Percentage calculated in the reference of parent wrapper of jqGrid.